# Xcode wants me to push Facebook and Live SDKs

Tags: xcode

I'm making an iOS app with Facebook and Microsoft Live integration, so I included their respective SDKs.

After that, every time I want to push my code to my repo, Xcode also wants to push the SDKs to their repos.

[image]

Even though I made no changes, and I even tried to remove their repos from the Organizer's repo list. Whenever I click Push, they are automatically re-added to the list.

How can I prevent this from happening?